# What prevent me from creating my own nameserver?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nameserver

Let's say I buy a domain from GoDadday `www.example.com`. What prevents me from configuring the name server to point to `ns1.myownserver.com`. And in `ns1.myownserver.com` I can create any kind of mapping I want?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing this, and many domains do exactly that.

Comment: `What prevents me from configuring the name server to point to ns1.myownserver.com` - Nothing prevents you from doing this.

Comment: I guess what I wanted to follow was. If nothing prevents me then I can have a malicious nameserver that might pollute the DNS?

Comment: @Zanko You can create records for `microsoft.com` all you like. Without *your* nameserver in *that* domain's WHOIS record, no one's going to ask you for those records.

Comment: THings have nothing to do with whois. As long as there is no DNS delegation to your nameserver, noone will query it for a zone like `microsoft.com`

Answer (score 2):

When a DNS client wants to look up `www.example.com.`, they will follow the delegation from the root to `com.` to `example.com.`, and then ask `ns1.myownserver.com.`.  However, the delegation from `com.` is only good for the `example.com.` zone.  All other zones -- for example, `serverfault.com.` -- would be outside that zone of authority, and have their own delegations, and your `ns1.myownserver.com.` will not be consulted.

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for. But one thing still confuse me is that my `ns1.myownserver.com` would still need to do DNS propagation right? What is I propagate malicious mapping ?

Comment: @Zanko DNS "propagation" is a bit of a misnomer. All it actually means is that records returned by your nameservers during lookups may be stored temporarily by caching resolvers elsewhere. If your nameserver isn't authoritative for a domain, those resolvers will never contact your nameserver for it, so those records don't "propagate" anywhere.